# Netbeans/Eclipse extracting GUI code

Tags: java, eclipse, emacs, netbeans

Is there a plugin that would allow me to design the GUI in eclipse or netbeans and then extract the source code to be used in another environment?

I am much more comfortable using emacs for my development but gui design is much easier with a WYSIWYG environment. What i am looking for is design the frame in eclipse/netbeans and then extract just gui code so i can import it to my project?

Like [JFrameBuilder](http://www.mars3000.com/index.html)does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with using both Netbeans/Eclipse and emacs on the same set of files?

1. Use Netbeans or Eclipse to design GUI.
2. Close Netbeans/Eclipse.
3. Open Emacs and code away.
4. Close Emacs.
5. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: This seems like a good approach; I use the same thing in Visual Studio.  But emacs has an autorevert.el, which reverts (re-opens) files that are being visited, when those files get changed outside of emacs. I think it is off by default, but I turn it on in buffers where I may be editing in an IDE. use this in your java-mode-hook: (turn-on-auto-revert-mode)  Also, you may not have to close netbeans/Eclipse to get this to work.  They may be smart enough to have an auto-revert equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, what I have experienced is that GUI design in Swing is best done without a WYSIWYG. I came into Java after many years of developing applications with Delphi, and at that time there was no suitable GUI designer for Swing, which was a bit of a shock for me.

In order for a manual UI design/coding to be efficient a really good layout manager should be used. [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) is one of such layout managers. Since I've started using it I have never looked back at WYSIWIG tools -- a sheet of paper, a pencil, MigLayout and a full control over your code.